# Would like to know if my stellar node running properly?

Tags: stellar-core, ledger, catchup, quorum

Below is what I see on the web frontend at http://my-dummy-stellar-node-domain.com:11626/info

To my limited knowledge about Stellar, I see that ledger hash is not changing. Is that a healthy sign?

My node was done owing to the issue with underlying hardware for a week or two, can I assume the node is still catching up?

[image: web frontend info]

Comment: Ledger hash never changes from "792e01c1476e931dc753289d4d76d1b2641f65201fcb056bec4d2d5f430ba2af". Stellarbeat.io says my node is only a watcher not validator although it is set to validate in conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re running a very old build that cannot understand what the current network is doing. Upgrade to the latest one (11.4.0 at this time)

Comment: Any reference or advice on how to upgrade? Would the old ledgers be retained?

Answer (score 1):

The best-known way is to pull the latest source code from the repository and build it and the peer nodes then need to vote for the upgrade. The good news is that the upgrade doesn't affect your databases.